# .NET MVC3 update database

Tags: .net, database, asp.net-mvc-3, http-post

By debugging I could see it updates  old entry with my new model entry. However it doesn't save changes, although I called the submit changes method.

```
    public ActionResult EditGameDetails(artikel model){

        artikel old = myShop.artikels.Single(m => m.artikelnummer == model.artikelnummer);
        old = model;

        myShop.SubmitChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Games","Game");
    }
```

Have I forgotten any codes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't simply set old to model because these are two different instances of the object. The one bound to the actionresult is not being tracked by your ORM. The following should work.

```
public ActionResult EditGameDetails(artikel model){

    artikel old = myShop.artikels.Single(m => m.artikelnummer == model.artikelnummer);
    old.prop1 = model.prop1;
    old.prop2 = model.prop2;

    myShop.SubmitChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Games","Game");
}
```

You can also use a tool such as automapper if you don't want to manually type all the property assignments.

Comment: great. it worked. thank you for your answer and also for the advice.
I'll try it in the future.

Comment: @kk-dev11 - if he answered your question, then you should mark it as answered.